# SwiftUI: How to disable onDelete's effect on list with multi-selection when on edit mode

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

On this screen, I'm on edit mode on a list with multi selection. I'm hoping to remove the red button to the left

[image: preview screenshot]

Here's relevant part of code.

So far I'm trying to toggle the definition of `perform` on `onDelete` trying to trick it to thinking that it's not does not have onDelete when on editing mode

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    
    @Query private var products: [Product]
    
    @State private var selectedProducts: Set<Product> = []
    @State var editMode: EditMode = .inactive

    private func deleteProduct(at offsets: IndexSet) {
        for index in offsets {
            modelContext.delete(products[index])
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                NavigationLink(destination: ProductView()) {
                    Text("Add Product")
                }
                .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
                .tint(.blue)

                List(selection: $selectedProducts) {
                    ForEach(products, id: \.self) { product in
                        NavigationLink(destination: ProductView(product: product)) {
                                HStack {
                                    Text(product.name)
                                    Spacer()
                                    Text(product.price, format: .currency(code: "PHP"))
                                    Text("QTY: \(String(product.stock))")
                                        .frame(width: 72, alignment: .leading)
                                        .padding(.leading, 8)
                                }
                        }
                    }
                    .onDelete(perform: editMode == .active ? nil : deleteProduct)
//                    .onDelete(perform: deleteProduct)
//                    .deleteDisabled(editMode == .active)
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Home")
            .toolbar {
                EditButton()
            }
            .environment(\.editMode, $editMode)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't get it, when does `onDelete` perform? As I see it, it will always disabled.

Comment: My understanding of `onDelete` is that it would allow swipe to delete action on each list item. I want that part but another effect of onDelete is that red circular stop icon when the list is in edit mode.

It seems to me that it's always enabled (since I can access the swipe to delete) but it's not "deactivating" when on editMode despite the ternary.

Let me know if that somewhat answers your question.

Comment: What is the actor named EditButton in the code?  Is that a button labeled 'Done' in the picture?

Comment: "So far I'm trying to toggle the definition of perform on onDelete trying to trick it to thinking that it's not does not have onDelete when on editing mode" is not a comprehensible sentence.  So how are you going to toggle between Edit and Unedit modes?  Do you have a button somewhere to use?

Comment: ` .toolbar { EditButton() }.environment(\.editMode, $editMode)` -- EditButton toggles the environment variable $editMode.

I verified that the $editMode changes when clicking the `EditButton()` by rendering some text depending on the state.

However List always behaves as though `perform` is set to `deleteProduct()`, not `nil`, despite the ternary with `editMode`

Comment: EditButton is from Apple -- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/editbutton